# Marking the highest high of each day (in a 24 h period only marking the highest bar)

Tags: pine-script

I need help marking only the HIGHEST BAR of each day.

This code i came up with marks the highest and lowest bars but only on the most recent day. Any ideas on how i can change the code such that it marks each days highest and lowest bars?

using the highest(high,bars) will return the values of all the highest bars.

Sorry if i posted this in wrong tags, It wont let me use pinescript tag cuz im a new user please can anyone change the tag on this to pinescript

```
study("NewDay", overlay = true)

YY = year(time)
MM = month(time)
DD = dayofmonth(time)
Date = timestamp(YY, MM, DD, 0, 0)

newDay = (Date != Date[1])
bars = int(1440/timeframe.multiplier)

c = barssince(newDay) >= 0 and (barssince(newDay) < bars)

hb = c ? highestbars(high,bars) : na
lb = c ? lowestbars(low,bars) : na

// plot(Date)
bgcolor(newDay? color.gray : na , transp = 80)
bgcolor(color.red, offset = hb,show_last = 1, transp = 70)
bgcolor(color.green,offset = lb, show_last = 1, transp = 70)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will mark the high/low bars.
Notice that I excluded today's session with `isHist`, because there's no telling which is the highest/lowest bar for the active session. If you would include today's session, you'd see the script mark each bar that makes a new high/low.

```
//@version=4
study("Color highest bar", overlay = true)

newSession = change(time('D'))

[lo,hi] = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', [low,high], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

isToday = (year == year(timenow)) and (month == month(timenow)) and (dayofmonth == dayofmonth(timenow))
isHist  = not isToday

lobar   = lo == low
hibar   = hi == high

bgcolor(newSession       ? color.white  : na, transp = 75)
bgcolor(lobar and isHist ? color.red    : na, transp = 75)
bgcolor(hibar and isHist ? color.green  : na, transp = 75)
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much. Your code is simple, works beautifully and i also learned from it. Thanks so much for taking the time to solve this!! Damn i made it so complicated :D

Answer (score 0):

Very Nice and simple code,
updated code for further reference

```
//@version=5
indicator("Color Highest & Lowest  Bars", overlay=true)
Show_New_Day = input.bool(defval = false,title = " Hide New Day",tooltip = "This will Show New Day On Chart",inline='1',group = "QuickSetup",display=display.all - display.status_line)

Time=time("1D")
isnewday = ta.change(Time) > 0

bgClr = isnewday ? close > open  ? color.new(color.green,90) :color.new(color.red,90) : isnewday ? close > open  ? color.new(color.green,100) :color.new(color.red,100):na

bgcolor(Show_New_Day  ? bgClr : na)

[TDO,TDH,TDL,TDC,TDR,TDMR] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,"D", [open[0],high[0],low[0],close[0],(high[0]-low[0]),hl2[0]], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

lobar   = TDL == low
hibar   = TDH == high

barcolor(lobar ? color.new(#edf900, 0): na)
barcolor(hibar ? color.new(#4e00f8, 0): na)
```